Is the following object a lattice?
I'd like to check that the following object is a lattice, since I'm having trouble understanding what I read as a slight ambiguity in the definition I've got in front of me.
The set $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2,3, 4\}\}$ equipped with the ordering of inclusion.
The ambiguity is that the definition says that each pair needs to have a unique supremum. Does this mean unique in the sense that it's unique to that pair, or unique in the sense that there is only one such thing?
"Unique to that pair" doesn't make sense to me, because then a lot of examples seem to fall apart, but I'd just like to check.

If suprema (or infima) exist, then they must be unique. Here, the supremum of the empty set and ${\emptyset}$ are equal to the empty set, the supremum of ${{x}}$ and ${\emptyset,{x}}$ are equal to ${x}$ for $x \in {1,2,3,4}$, and the supremum of any other subset is ${1,2,3,4}$.

The word "unique" is frustratingly ambiguous in mathematics and probably it should be avoided. Suprema are actually necessarily unique in the sense that if $a, b$ are two suprema of the same subset then necessarily $a = b$, so it's not necessary to stipulate this in the definition of a lattice. "Unique" here does not mean that the function from pairs to their suprema is injective.

There are some books that define the supremum using a "negative" condition, similar to how a maximal (not maximum) element is defined: According to this definition, $s$ is supremum of a pair of elements $a, b$ of a poset if $s$ is an upper bound of $a, b$ and there exists no upper bound $s'$ of $a, b$ such that $s < s'$. By this definition, a pair of elements can have multiple suprema, so a lattice is defined as a poset in which every pair of elements has a unique supremum and a unique infimum.

Minimal upper bounds and maximal lower bounds are not useful. A poset could have a unique minimal element that is not a least element, or dually, a unique maximal element that is not a greatest element (just take $P \cup {m}$, where $m$ is a new element incomparable with all elements of $P$ and $P$ has no minimal or maximal elements).

Thank you, I appreciate the clarification and insight. For the sake of good housekeeping, if anyone wants to turn a comment into an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

That corresponds to one possible labelling of lattice $\mathbf M_4$.
Here's a representation of the Hasse diagram of $\mathbf M_n$, to get an idea:

In your case, $n=4$, $x_i = \{i\}$, $0=\emptyset$, and $1=\{1,2,3,4\}$.
It's exactly what Geoffrey Trang wrote in the first comment.
You are right in your interpretation of uniqueness of suprema (and the same applies to infima): it means that, for each pair $x,y$ of elements of the lattice, there is one element (which we sometimes denote by $x \vee y$), called the supremum of $x$ and $y$, and it is such that $x \leq x \vee y$ and $y \leq x \vee y$; furthermore, if $x \leq u$ and $y \leq u$, then $x \vee y \leq u$, that is, the supremum of $x$ and $y$ is the least upper bound (the least among those which are above) of $x$ and $y$.
In particular, if $u$ and $v$ are both the suprema of $x$ and $y$, it follows that $u \leq v$ (because they're both upper bounds and $u$, being the supremum, is the least of them), and $v \leq u$ (for the same reason).
Then it follows from anti-symmetry of partial order relations that $u=v$.
So the uniqueness doesn't have to be stated in the definition, since it follows from it (as Qiaochu Yuan wrote)
